# Dynamically find the mouse event id in /dev/input/event*

Tags: c++, linux, mouse

I am using this code to read mouse input event in linux .

```
      #define MOUSEFILE "/dev/input/event13"

      if((fd = open(MOUSEFILE, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("opening device");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      while(read(fd, &ie, sizeof(struct input_event)))
      {

      }
```

i manually use `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` in the terminal to find the event id of my connected mouse and it is different every-time i restart linux . Is there a way through which i could dynamically find the event id's of my connected mouse .

Comment: The proper way is write a custom udev rule. ... But!... Why don't you just use `/dev/input/mice` ?

Comment: Does that have same format of input events as that /dev/input/event* , as i have already written a long code and don't want to change it .

Comment: no, it don't share the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the same device name using a custom udev rule. See [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=18942) for example.

Essentally, just create a file under `/etc/udev/rule.d` with something like this:

```
 KERNEL=="event*", SYSFS{manufacturer}=="Microsoft", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0023", NAME="input/mstrackball"
```

You can find the product id and other stuffs in your sysfs.